# Texarea onfocus, on blur with javascript

Tags: javascript, html, forms, textarea

I am looking for a way to control the default value, onfocus and onblur of textarea with JavaScript

*(I know that:

- The default value in textarea is : `<textarea name="text">  Default value </textarea>`

- There is some solutions with html5 and with jQuery. But here I am looking for a pure JavaScript solution)*

Can I have this applied to textarea?:

```
form name="form1" action="comprovar.php" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="name" value="name" 
        onfocus="if (this.value=='name') this.value = '';" 
        onblur="if (this.value=='') this.value = 'name';"   
    />
 </form>
```

How can I get onfocus and on blur here?:

```
<textarea name="text">  Write here </textarea>
```

The example live here: http://jsfiddle.net/sKvMa/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can have `onfocus` and `onblur` on the textarea *exactly* like how you can from your input. See this demo: http://jsfiddle.net/sKvMa/1/

```
<textarea name="text" 
    onfocus="if (this.value=='Write here') this.value = '';" 
    onblur="if (this.value=='') this.value = 'Write here';" >Write here</textarea>
```

Comment: Yes, i agree. Was only demonstrating the concept.

Comment: BTW, if its *just* for placeholder text, then you are better off using the `placeholder` HTML feature (old versions of IE will having trouble coping though)

Comment: @Nrc - See my edit for the default value setting, i've used 'Write here' as default for example.

Comment: Inline JS is generally bad because a) it cannot be cached and has to be served everytime, b) you cannot minify/compress it or apply any other kind of optimized serving strategy and c) it reduces the readability of your HTML (HTML is ideally used *only* for the presentation, the *behavior* which comes from JS should ideally come from else where)

Comment: Your answer is clear and simple. Thank you. I understand the downside of inline. HTML5 is simple and clear but if I have to provide a alternative to IE, everything is too complicated. Is JQuery the best solution?

Comment: For the placeholder requirement, you do not really need jQuery. Your solution above should be more than enough, but if you have a considerable amount of JavaScript in your application, jQuery is definitely worth considering. It will surely save hours of development time.

Answer (score 1):

You can actually achieve this without using JavaScript at all, although it is a feature of HTML5, so it works in modern browsers.

```
<textarea name="text" placeholder="Write here"></textarea>
```

Depending on what you are using the placeholder for, this may suit you as it is much simpler to implement and maintain that a scripted solution.

Comment: Can I use only this HTML5 solution? If I have to provide a alternative solution with jQuery or JavaScript that works everywhere, why even consider to include the HTML5 solution too?

Comment: I personally just use this. No JavaScript or jQuery. It works in IE10 and pretty much everything else.

Answer (score 1):

In new browsers you can use `placeholder` attribute. [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sKvMa/7/)
For browsers which don't support placeHolder

```
    if( !'placeholder' in document.createElement("input") ){

        var input =  document.getElementsByTagName("input"),
            textArea = document.getElementsByTagName("textarea");
    for(var k = 0; k < input.length; k++){
         input[k].value= "name";
        input[k].onblur = function(){
            if(this.value == "") this.value = "name"
        }
        input[k].onfocus = function(){
            if(this.value == "name") this.value = ""
        }
    }
    for(var k = 0; k < textArea .length; k++){
          textArea [k].value= "name";
        textArea [k].onblur = function(){
            if(this.value == "") this.value = "name"
        }
        textArea [k].onfocus = function(){
            if(this.value == "name") this.value = ""
        }
    }
}
​​
```

Answer (score 0):

or you can target from jQuery like this

```
var mytext = $("textarea[name='text']").val();
```

then you could compare the text

```
if (mytext == 'Write here')
  //do this
else
  //do that
```

Comment: Possibly because it is incomplete. However, this would be an inappropriate use of downvoting for answers - which really should only be downvoted if providing misleading or plain wrong answers. If the downvoter believes this to be the case, he should add a comment to that effect, otherwise he himself is merely being misleading (and a troll). Brought it back to zero, at least!